# Handling errors in jQuery(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing JS that is used in a web framework, and is frequently mixed in with other developers' (often error-prone) jQuery code. Unfortunately errors in their jQuery(document).ready blocks prevent mine from executing. Take the following simple sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        nosuchobject.fakemethod();       //intentionally cause major error
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello!");                 //never executed
    });
</script>
```

Shouldn't the second ready block execute regardless of what happened in the previous? Is there a "safe" way to run jQuery(document).ready that will run even in the case of previous errors?

EDIT: I have no control/visibility over the error-prone blocks as they're written by other authors and mixed in arbitrarily.

Comment: Three people made bad decisions here. The first one raised errors in ready blocks. The second one convinced jQuery devs that those errors should literally prevent the rest of the page from loading. And the third one is myself, for still using jQuery 1.9.1 in 2020. I think I should just quit.

Comment: Turns out `api.jquery.com` uses `jquery-1.11.3`

Comment: For the record, I tested jQuery 3.5.1 and it works as expected, the second block runs. I found a thread from 2011 discussing this behavior, where people decided that the rest of the blocks should not run. I am glad they revisited that decision later. https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10251

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't tried this code, but it should work (at least, the idea should anyway). <s>Make sure you include it AFTER jquery, but BEFORE any potentially buggy scripts.</s> (Not necessary, see comments.)

```
var oldReady = jQuery.ready;
jQuery.ready = function(){
  try{
    return oldReady.apply(this, arguments);
  }catch(e){
    // handle e ....
  }
};
```

Comment: This seems to work quite well, regardless of whether it goes before or after the potentially buggy scripts. I think what I'll do is move the contents of my ready block (alert("Hello!") in the sample) to just after the catch block. That way my ready block can "append" itself to the end of the previous ready blocks.

Comment: Great solution. Never even thought of that.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking, but this'll work no matter where it goes, as long as it's in the <head> tag and not in some onload event, since we're hijacking the ready method before it gets invoked on dom load.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, both of the `ready` blocks are essentially combined into one given the way jQuery works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      nosuchobject.fakemethod();       //intentionally cause major error
      alert("Hello!");                 //never executed
  });
</script>
```

So that's why its not alerting per the error above. I don't believe there is a way to fix this to make every `ready` function run regardless of former failures.

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted wrapping the error-prone commands in try...catch brackets?

```
$(function(){
    try {
        noObject.noMethod();
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    }
});

$(function(){
    try {
        alert("Hello World");
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

To avoid potential confusion, `$(function(){ ... });` is functionally the same as `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control/visibility over the blocks that throw the errors. In the sample above, the first jQuery(document).ready block comes from someone else's code. Thus unfotunately I don't have a way of wrapping them in try/catch blocks.

This is part of a web framework where arbitrary plugins can load together in the head of the document.

Comment: You should mention in your question that you don't have access to their code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution, it will wrap any function sent to ready with try-catch block:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.oldReady = $.fn.ready;
    $.fn.ready = function(fn){
        return $.fn.oldReady( function(){ try{ if(fn) fn.apply($,arguments); } catch(e){}} );
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could re-reference jQuery before each of your code blocks.  Your code would then use the fresh instance of the library, and it would execute.  I've tested this in Safari 4.0.3 on OSX.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            nosuchobject.fakemethod();       //intentionally cause major error
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Hello!");                 //executed!
        });
    </script>   

</head>
<body>

<p>hello world</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Terrible idea...this'll at the very least force the user to download the library twice, and could also cause issues with static variables and objects being overwritten.

Comment: The user's browser only re-downloads the remote file when a cache buster is put in place. In my example, the browser reads the second jQuery reference from cache. It isn't pretty, but it helps solve the original problem.  Regarding issues with static variables and objects, do you mean within the jQuery library itself, or user defined static variables and objects?  In case of an overwrite, jQuery maps over itself. In my example, the correctly written second block would reference the fresh instance of jQuery.  Can you please elaborate on the issues you mention?  Thanks!

Comment: Right at the beginning of jquery, you'll see this: jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {...}. Since those objects aren't extended but are instantiated, anything that modifies or touches those properties (and indeed, anything else set statically at the jquery level) will be trashed. And even if the browser did cache the js, it will still have to re-parse it and re-load all the declared elements, degrading the user experience (not to mention it'd probably introduce memory leaks because there's no cleanup of any dom events).