# jQuery $(document).ready error blocking footer script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

So I've got a unique problem.

I've got a site that I can't edit the template for at all, I can only alter the embedded script.

This embedded script is injected into the footer of the site in question.

The embedded script relies on `$(document).ready` to kick itself off.

The problem is, a script higher up on the page throws an error in it's `$(document).ready` function which prevents my `$(document).ready` from ever being called.

I tried setting up a `try .. catch` block, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890512/handling-errors-in-jquerydocument-ready), but I believe this will only work if my script is higher up on the page still.

My question, is it possible to get my `$(document).ready` call to run, even if it's lower on the page, and a previous one has errors?

In the site above my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#logo').vAlign();
  });
</script>
```

`.vAlign();` is not defined so it's throwing: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

In my embedded js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready!');
});
```

I never see "ready!" in the console.

Comment: Using finally to call a method or function(ready-function) as third codeblock of try-catch is a possibility because finally-codeblock is always executed no matter what error has been thrown.

Comment: @Blauharley could you elaborate how to use this in an answer using my edit above?

Comment: Or instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... })` you could simply use `(function() { ... })()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error in one script tag in the page doesn't keep other scripts from running.

Example:

```
<script>
    $(function(){ console.log(1); });
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){ console.log 2; });
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){ console.log(3); });
</script>
```

This will first log a syntax error for the second script tag, then it will log the values 1 and 3 as the other ready events work fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/am4f7f18/

Comment: I thought this was the case as well! But there's definite issue here. Please see my edit with the exact code being used.

Comment: @goddamnyouryan: Aha, the type of the error matters. Although a syntax error doesn't stop other scripts, a runtime error in a `ready` event handler stops the following handlers from running. Unfortunately it also keeps the `load` event from working, which would otherwise be an alternative. I had an idea that you could unbind the faulty `ready` event before it happened, but I couldn't get that to work...

Comment: yeah I tried unbinding it as well but it wasn't working for me either. I'm convinced there's a way to handle this, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

When important operations must always be executed finally-codeblock of try-catch could be used. Even if catch-codeblock is not run through finally-codeblock is and so **callReady**-function is called definitely at the end no matter whether there was an error or not(except for syntax errors). As it is the case below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  try{
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#logo').vAlign();
    });
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
  finally{
    // some fallback code might be executed here
    callReady();
  }


  jQuery(document).ready(callReady);

  function callReady(){
    console.log('ready!');
  }

</script>
```

Unfortunately if there is no error **callReady** is called twice(because finally is always run through at the end) but you can check for this case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var errorHappened = true;

  function checkForErrors(callback){

      callback();

      // when interpreter reaches this point no error with business-code is thrown
      errorHappened = false;

  }

  try{
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      try{

        checkForErrors(function(){

            // put business-code in here

            $('#logo').vAlign();

        })


      }
      finally{
        if(errorHappened){
            callReady();
        }
      }

    });
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }


  jQuery(document).ready(callReady);

  function callReady(){
    console.log('ready!');
  }

</script>
```

Comment: This is very helpful, however the  `$('#logo').vAlign();` code is the code that I can't touch, which means I can't wrap it in a try block.